# How to convert comma-separated strings to Cassandra list format in Vim?

Tags: regex, list, vim, replace, cassandra

I would like to convert an all-comma-separated string literal in double quotes, such as the following:

```
"hello,world,stack,overflow"
```

into the [Cassandra list format](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#collections):

```
"['hello','world','stack','overflow']"
```

where each element is embraced in single quotes, and the whole original string is embraced in square brackets and double quotes. How can I do it in Vim?

In my input, such quoted comma-separated strings are parts of rows in a CSV-formatted table. Below is an example:

```
other,fields,123,456,"hello,world,stack,overflow"
second,row,567,890,"another,comma,separated,string"
...
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
other,fields,123,456,"['hello','world','stack','overflow']"
second,row,567,890,"['another','comma','separated','string']"
...
```

None of my target strings span multiple lines.

Comment: How many of these do you have? Are they one per line? Regex can't do a very good job matching quotes (ie can't tell the first from the last) Although you might be able to get away with it if there were no other quotes on the line.

Comment: There are at least one per line.  Actually it's a csv file.

Comment: Can you give an example file?

Comment: Here you go.  Let me know if something is not clear :)

Comment: I would recommend using a macro if you know there will be exactly four fields in the string.

Comment: But actually I have more than one of those files, and some of them use different schemas, but it's fine for me to use a slightly different way to do find and replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
:%s/\v(".*)@<=\s*([^,"]+)\s*(.*")@=/'\2'/g
:%s/"/"[
:%s/"\[\@!/]"
```

Or all at once

```
:%s/\v(".*)@<=\s*([^,"]+)\s*(.*")@=/'\2'/ge | %s/"/"[/e | %s/"\[\@!/]"
```

This works on the example. This will not work if there more than one pair of quotes on the line.

Explanation

```
:%s/\v(".*)@<=\s*([^,"]+)\s*(.*")@=/'\2'/g
```

This looks for a string that has a quote before and after it with lookaheads and lookbehinds. Then we capture everything that isn't a comma or a quote and replace it with the captured part in single quotes. This throws out any leading or trailing spaces.

```
:%s/"/"[
```

This should be self explanatory if you have used `:s` before

```
:%s/"\[\@!/]"
```

This uses a negative lookahead to find the first quote that isn't followed by a left bracket and replaces it with a right bracket and a quote.

---

After thinking about this a bit more I think you can do the whole file in one shot regardless of weather there are more than one pair of quotes on the line.

The first function is just a helper function that makes the substitute command a little easier to type. (You could have done three substitute commands in a single line but that would have been ugly). It does the same thing as the stuff above.

```
function! ReplaceCommaSeperated(string)
    let l:tmp = substitute(a:string, '[^,"]\+', "'\\0'", 'g')
    let l:tmp = substitute(l:tmp, '"', '"[', '')
    return substitute(l:tmp, '"\[\@!', ']"', '')
endfunction

function! RunCommaReplace()
    %s/".\{-}"/\=ReplaceCommaSeperated(submatch(0))/g 
endfunction
```

The second function finds all quoted strings and passes it off to the function and it gets replaced all at once. And you know which one is the beginning and end quotes because there is guaranteed to be only one pair of quotes.

The reason this works and that the regex parser doesn't get confused is that the pattern matching starts after the end of the first match. So if you had the string `" A "  B " C "`
 `" A "` would be the first match and `" C "` would be the second match because when the parser tried to match after B it would see `B " C "` and that doesn't match.

To run this in your vim just copy the two function into your vimrc. And in the file you want to run this run the following command.

```
:call RunCommaReplace()
```

Comment: It's time for me to check what each individual symbol means, and hopefully I can find how to handle more than one pair of quotes.

Comment: @keelar regex is really the wrong job for this. It can't tell the difference between `" (this) " (that) "` Since all its doing is pattern matching. It can't tell which one is correctly paired. For instance is this or that the one thats properly quoted. However most of the symbols can be found in `:h pattern-searches`

Comment: If it's acceptable for me to replace those strings one column at a time, will that make things easier? (for example, the columns I would like to replace are 3rd and 5th, and it's acceptable for me to issue two different find/replace to convert them)

Comment: @keelar that sounds like it should be fine if you can get it to work

Comment: @keelar I added a function that should do the whole file at once regardless of how many pairs of quotes there are in the line. Not sure if you needed it anymore but I figured its worth sharing.

Comment: Great thanks! I still need this as I have many of them to convert, and my previous work-around does not work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** It is quite possible to solve the problem in a single run of the
`:substitute` command. I can see two slightly different implementations
of such approach. Both of them follow the same pattern of a substitution
with an expression:

```
:%s/"\([^"]*\)"/\='"['..Q..']"'/g
```

According to the command above, all sequences of zero or more characters
enclosed in double quotes get replaced with the result of evaluation of
the expression specified after the `\=` sign (see `:help sub-replace-\=`).
To be concatenated with the surrounding brackets and quotes is the
substitution expression `Q` standing for an expression transforming
the text of a comma-separated list—captured by the (only) submatch of
the pattern—into a string of the same list with items enclosed in
single quotes.

The two versions of the expression `Q` are as follows.

**2.** The first version is straightforward:

1. Break the matched text down into a list of elements using comma
   as a separator:

   ```
   split(submatch(1), ',', 1)
   ```

   (The last argument is optional here and is necessary only when
   empty elements are possible at the beginning or the ending of
   the double-quoted field.)
2. Surround them with quotes:

   ```
   map(‹…›, '"''"..v:val.."''"')
   ```
3. And concatenate them back in order, alternating with the
   separating comma:

   ```
   join(‹…›, ',')
   ```

Combining these steps, we obtain the expression

```
join(map(split(submatch(1), ',', 1), '"''"..v:val.."''"'), ',')
```

**3.** The second, a bit more performant version of the expression `Q`
is not much more complicated; it is just a substitution (inside of
a substitution, as `Q` is inside of the `:s` command). At our disposal
we have the `substitute()` function which has the power equivalent to
the command of the same name.

The expression

```
substitute(submatch(1), '[^,]\+', "'&'", 'g')
```

results in all occurrences of nonempty character sequences that do not
contain commas, being changed to themselves with single quotes attached
at both ends.

If we want this expression to also handle empty list items (as the
first variant above does), all we need to do is change the last
pattern to

```
'\%(^\|,\)\zs[^,]*'
```

This way, it allows empty sequences, too, but under the restriction of
them being either at the very beginning or after a comma. (See `:help \zs`
and `:help \%(` to better understand how the changed pattern works.)

**4.** Thus, we can use either of the following two commands:

```
:%s/"\([^"]*\)"/\='"['..join(map(split(submatch(1),',',1),'"''"..v:val.."''"'),',')..']"'/g
```

or

```
:%s/"\([^"]*\)"/\='"['..substitute(submatch(1),'\%(^\|,\)\zs[^,]*',"'&'",'g')..']"'/g
```

Both of them work for all quoted fields on a line.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, too!  Would you mind explaining this a little bit further?

Comment: @keelar:  Sure.  I have added a detailed explanation along with a second implementation of the same single-pass approach.  Please let me know what do you think about it.  I hope you will find it helpful.